# Using multivariate hypergeometric distribution to compute probability of multiple events

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-function

I am new here. I have researched this for over a month and spoken to 3 University professors and have not quite gotten the accuracy I am looking for.

I am writing C# to compute probability based on user input and information in a database. I can calculate the probability of drawing at least x in a hand of y cards from a deck of N cards where the number of successes in N = m. This is assuming WITHOUT replacement.

For example, if I want to know what the probability of drawing at least 3 cards of type A in a hand of 7 cards from a deck of 60 cards where there are 10 cards of type A, I would do the following:

Using hypergeometric distribution formula, find probability of drawing exactly 3, exactly 4, exactly 5, exactly 6 and exactly 7. Then add those. My calculations appear to be correct. (If not, please explain)

What I want to do is introduce a second or even a third condition. For instance, picking at least 2 of type A, at least 1 of type B, and at least 3 of type C. I think that in this example the following would be correct:

outcome1 = exactly 2 A * exactly 1 B * exactly 3 C

outcome2 = exactly 3 A * exactly 1 B * exactly 3 C

outcome3 = exactly 2 A * exactly 2 B * exactly 3 C

outcome4 = exactly 2 A * exactly 1 B * exactly 4 C

Final probability = outcome1 + outcome2 + outcome3 + outcome4

How can I calculate the number of outcomes and their respective probabilities and then sum them? If possible, can you explain with words instead of math symbols so I can take those concepts and apply them in C# language? I am limited by the amount of digits I can hold in a variable so doing large factorials has been interesting. The steps to calculate in C# are numerous. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you want the Multinomial Hypergeometric Disctribution. See here for formula (pmf) and example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this I think...

Say I want know the probability of drawing at least 1 of Type A and at least 2 of type B with the remainder being any combination. SO...

Successes for type A = 10 Successes for Type B = 5 Undetermined = 45 Total = 60

- p(1 of A & 2 of B) = (10choose1 * 5choose2 * 45choose4) / 60choose7
- p(1 of A & 3 of B) = (10choose1 * 5choose3 * 45choose3) / 60choose7
- p(1 of A & 4 of B) = (10choose1 * 5choose4 * 45choose2) / 60choose7
- p(1 of A & 5 of B) = (10choose1 * 5choose5 * 45choose1) / 60choose7
- p(2 of A & 2 of B) = (10choose2 * 5choose2 * 45choose3) / 60choose7
- p(2 of A & 3 of B) = (10choose2 * 5choose3 * 45choose2) / 60choose7
- p(2 of A & 4 of B) = (10choose2 * 5choose4 * 45choose1) / 60choose7
- p(2 of A & 5 of B) = (10choose2 * 5choose2) / 60choose7
- p(3 of A & 2 of B) = (10choose3 * 5choose2 * 45choose2) / 60choose7
- p(3 of A & 3 of B) = (10choose3 * 5choose3 * 45choose1) / 60choose7
- p(3 of A & 4 of B) = (10choose3 * 5choose4) / 60choose7
- p(4 of A & 2 of B) = (10choose4 * 5choose2 * 45choose1) / 60choose7
- p(4 of A & 3 of B) = (10choose4 * 5choose3) / 60choose7
- p(5 of A & 2 of B) = (10choose5 * 5choose2) / 60choose7

Final Probability = above outcomes added together.

Comment: This all looks mathematically correct to me. However, I doubt very much that it is the computationally best way to arrive at the answer. In cases like this, with many factorials and sums of tiny probabilities, it is standard to rely on clever tricks to avoid implementing the math in the natural way that you represent it here. However, I can't give you details about what those clever tricks are. Heavy use of Stirling's formula? I don't know.

Comment: At a minimum (as you may have already realized) you certainly should not be dividing by 60 choose 7 until delivering your final answer.