# How to find the probability of two events that overlap in satisfying multiple conditions?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been using multivariate calculations to figure out the probability of drawing at least x of type A and at least y of type B cards in an opening hand of 7 from a deck of 60 cards WITHOUT replacement. I am converting it to C# to programmatically calculate the probability based on user input. [Full details here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439919/using-multivariate-hypergeometric-distribution-to-compute-probability-of-multipl). For example:

User Input:

- s5 = 5 possible successful outcomes
- s10 = 10 possible successful outcomes
- n1 = drawing at least 1 in 7
- n2 = drawing at least 2 in 7

THEN

- if n1=1 and n2=2 then p = (5choose1 * 10choose2 * 45choose4)/60choose7
- if n1=2 and n2=2 then p = (5choose2 * 10choose2 * 45choose3)/60choose7
- and so on and then add the combinations for a total probability for at least 1 of Type A and at least 2 of Type B.

The problem I have run into is when Type A is also a member of Type B. For example, if I had a basket of fruits and vegetables and wanted to know what the probability was of blindly selecting at least 3 fruits with at least 1 of them being an apple.

I am having trouble researching this because I am not really sure what I should be looking for. How do I account for the possibility that an event can meet more than one condition?

Comment: One approach is to re-define Type B so it excludes Type A. In your example you would have types "Apple" (A), "Fruit Excluding Apples" (F), and "Vegetables" (V). For $\geq 1$ apple and $\geq 3$ fruit, you need one of: 1A2F, 1A3F, 1A4F, ... 2A1F, 2A2F, 2A3F, 2A4F, ... ,3A, 4A, 5A, ... -- using the same Multivariate Hypergeometric distribution that you have already used.

Comment: That makes sense. I will work on a solution. Thank you!